# Unable to install Django-nonrel

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I followed [this](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html#django-nonrel) link to install Django MongoDB Engine 
On running command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```

[image: This is what I am getting]

After hours of searching I could not successfully install django-nonrel.

Please guide me!

Answer (score 0):

Django-nonrel is deprecated.
See this -> https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel

If you want to use MongoDB with Django, then the path ain't gonna be an easy one. Use MongoEngine instead -> http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html.

Also if you are going to use Django REST Framework for your APIs, then you'll need Django Rest Framework MongoEngine too -> https://pythonhosted.org/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/